# Refractometers- Can the traditional prisms be substituted with some other component/s?

Tags: optics

Is there any way we can substitute the prism that is used in refractometers? For example, introduce other components like lenses or sensors instead of a prism? An idea which could be tried? Could someone help me out in this direction? Thanks in advance. The purpose is still to measure the refractive index.

Answer (score 0):

One can use diffraction gratings instead of prisms.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some coherent light, you could try a lattice or a double slit. The diffraction angle of a double slit is wavelength-dependent. See also [Double-Slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment). If the light is not coherent, this method also may be used. However, the details are more intricate: [Spatial coherence of sunlight and its
implications for light management in
photovoltaics](https://www.photonics.ethz.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/pdf/Papers/divitt15a.pdf)